# Sign certificate request with smartcard private key in PKCS#11

Tags: c++, openssl, signature, pkcs#11, csr

I would like to sign a certificate request with a smartcard's private key with PKCS#11. I do mean signing the CSR itself and not writing a certificate in response.

So I am using OpenSSL to create the X509 certificate request, and I want to use PKCS#11 and C_Sign to create the signature. How can I do that?

This is what I have currently, but when I try to generate a certificate from this request with OpenSSL CLI, it says the signature doesn't match so I must be doing something wrong. I'm not sure what to pass C_Sign —right now I've tried the output of i2d_X509_REQ()— and how to set the signature back in X509_REQ once it's been created (I've tried building an ASN1_BIT_STRING object).

Note: this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987043/sign-certificate-request-with-smartcard-private-key-in-pkcs11) because this one is for a certificate and works for an old version of OpenSSL's API. Although, I have tried to use the answer by manually exposing the internals of the X509_REQ structure (see last code block).

```
X509_REQ makeCSR() {
    /* Create OpenSSL EVP_PKEY from exported public key components */
    RSA* openssl_rsa = RSA_new();
    BIGNUM* bn_modulus = BN_bin2bn(modulus.data(), (int) modulus.size(), nullptr);
    BIGNUM* bn_public_exponent = BN_bin2bn(public_exponent.data(), (int) public_exponent.size(), nullptr);
    int success = RSA_set0_key(openssl_rsa, bn_modulus, bn_public_exponent, nullptr);
    EVP_PKEY* evp_pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();

    /* Add public key to certificate request */
    EVP_PKEY_assign(evp_pkey, EVP_PKEY_RSA, openssl_rsa);
    X509_REQ* request = X509_REQ_new();
    X509_REQ_set_pubkey(request, evp_pkey);

    /* Set certificate request attributes */
    // ...

    /* Sign certificate request with smart card */
    unsigned char* buffer { nullptr };
    int size = i2d_X509_REQ(request, &buffer);
    std::vector<unsigned char> der_encoded_request(buffer, buffer + size);
    std::vector<unsigned char> signature = smartcard->signCertificateRequest(der_encoded_request);

    /* Build signature object */
    ASN1_BIT_STRING* asn1_signature = ASN1_BIT_STRING_new();
    ASN1_BIT_STRING_set(asn1_signature, signature.data(), (int) signature.size());
    asn1_signature->flags &= ~(ASN1_STRING_FLAG_BITS_LEFT | 0x07);
    asn1_signature->flags |= ASN1_STRING_FLAG_BITS_LEFT;
    X509_ALGOR* x509_algor = X509_ALGOR_new();
    ASN1_OBJECT* a = OBJ_nid2obj(pkcs11SignatureAlgorithmToNid(CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS));
    X509_ALGOR_set0(x509_algor, a, V_ASN1_NULL, nullptr);

    /* Add signature to X509_REQ */
    X509_REQ_set1_signature_algo(request, x509_algor);
    X509_REQ_set0_signature(request, asn1_signature);
    return request;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> signCertificateRequest(std::vector<unsigned char>& certificate_request)
{
    CK_MECHANISM mechanism = { CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS, nullptr, 0 };
    auto result = s_pkcs11->fn->C_SignInit(m_session_handle, &mechanism, private_key_handle);

    unsigned long signature_length { 0 };
    result = pkcs11->C_Sign(m_session_handle,
                                  certificate_request.data(),
                                  (unsigned long) certificate_request.size(),
                                  nullptr,
                                  &signature_length);
    std::vector<unsigned char> signature(signature_length);
    result = pkcs11->C_Sign(m_session_handle,
                                  certificate_request.data(),
                                  (unsigned long) certificate_request.size(),
                                  signature.data(),
                                  &signature_length);
    return signature;
}
```

I've also tried exposing the internals of X509_REQ and passing the output of `i2d_X509_REQ_INFO(&request->req_info, &buffer)` to C_Sign; or using `ASN1_item_i2d()`; and also copying the signature output directly to request->signature->data.

```
    request->req_info.enc.modified = 1;
    X509_ALGOR_set0(&request->sig_alg,
                    OBJ_nid2obj(pkcs11SignatureAlgorithmToNid(CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS)),
                    V_ASN1_NULL,
                    nullptr);
    unsigned char* certDerBuf = NULL;
    const auto certDerLen = ASN1_item_i2d(ASN1_VALUE*) &request->req_info,
                                          &certDerBuf,
                                          ASN1_ITEM_rptr(X509_REQ_INFO));
    std::vector<unsigned char> certDerVec(certDerBuf, certDerBuf + certDerLen);
    std::vector<unsigned char> signature = smartcard->signCertificateRequest(certDerVec);
    request->signature->data = (unsigned char*) OPENSSL_malloc(signature.size());
    request->signature->length = (int) signature.size();
    request->signature->data = signature.data();
```

Comment: The whole security point of smartcard is not to be able to fetch private key from it on hardware level. So forget about reading  PKCS#11. You suppose to just sent some data to smardcard and it will give you back signed version of it. OpenSSL is not enough to handle that scenario. You need use some system API to access smartcard and ask it to sign something.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm using PKCS#11. I want to send the CSR to the smartcard so that it can sign it and return me the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem in the end; this is my complete solution. Error handling and PKCS#11 session handling have been omitted. I use a unique_ptr for managing OpenSSL resources. I had to expose OpenSSL's X509_REQ and X509_REQ_INFO structures because I couldn't find accessors for req_info in OpenSSL 1.1.1h.

```
// OpenSSL internal definitions
using CRYPTO_REF_COUNT = int;
struct X509_req_info_st {
    ASN1_ENCODING enc;     /* cached encoding of signed part */
    ASN1_INTEGER* version; /* version, defaults to v1(0) so can be NULL */
    X509_NAME* subject;    /* certificate request DN */
    X509_PUBKEY* pubkey;   /* public key of request */
    /*
     * Zero or more attributes.
     * NB: although attributes is a mandatory field some broken
     * encodings omit it so this may be NULL in that case.
     */
    STACK_OF(X509_ATTRIBUTE) * attributes;
};
struct X509_req_st {
    X509_REQ_INFO req_info;     /* signed certificate request data */
    X509_ALGOR sig_alg;         /* signature algorithm */
    ASN1_BIT_STRING* signature; /* signature */
    CRYPTO_REF_COUNT references;
    CRYPTO_RWLOCK* lock;
};

template<typename T>
using AutoDeletedPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>;

void makeCSR(const std::vector<unsigned char>& modulus,
             const std::vector<unsigned char>& public_exponent)
{
    /* Create OpenSSL EVP_PKEY from exported public key components */
    auto* openssl_rsa = RSA_new();
    auto bn_modulus = BN_bin2bn(modulus.data(), static_cast<int>(modulus.size()), nullptr);
    auto bn_public_exponent = BN_bin2bn(public_exponent.data(),
                                        static_cast<int>(public_exponent.size()),
                                        nullptr);
    auto success = RSA_set0_key(openssl_rsa, bn_modulus, bn_public_exponent, nullptr);

    auto key_file = AutoDeletedPtr<BIO>(BIO_new_file("key.pem", "wb"), BIO_free);
    PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(key_file.get(), openssl_rsa);

    auto evp_pkey = AutoDeletedPtr<EVP_PKEY>(EVP_PKEY_new(), EVP_PKEY_free);

    /* Add public key to certificate request */
    EVP_PKEY_assign(evp_pkey.get(), EVP_PKEY_RSA, openssl_rsa);

    auto request = AutoDeletedPtr<X509_REQ>(X509_REQ_new(), X509_REQ_free);

    X509_REQ_set_pubkey(request.get(), evp_pkey.get());

    /* Set certificate request attributes */
    // ...
    
    /* Sign certificate request with smart card */
    unsigned char* buffer { nullptr };
    auto size = i2d_X509_REQ_INFO(&request->req_info, &buffer);
    std::vector<unsigned char> der_encoded_request(buffer, buffer + size);

    auto signature = signCertificateRequest(der_encoded_request);

    auto asn1_signature = ASN1_BIT_STRING_new();

    ASN1_BIT_STRING_set(asn1_signature, signature.data(), static_cast<int>(signature.size()));
    auto x509_algor = AutoDeletedPtr<X509_ALGOR>(X509_ALGOR_new(), X509_ALGOR_free);
    auto* a = OBJ_nid2obj(pkcs11SignatureAlgorithmToNid(CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS));
    auto algor_set_result = X509_ALGOR_set0(x509_algor.get(), a, V_ASN1_NULL, nullptr);

    X509_REQ_set1_signature_algo(request.get(), x509_algor.get());
    X509_REQ_set0_signature(request.get(), asn1_signature);
    request->signature->flags &= ~(ASN1_STRING_FLAG_BITS_LEFT | 0x07);
    request->signature->flags |= ASN1_STRING_FLAG_BITS_LEFT;

    // Do what you want with the request
}

std::vector<unsigned char> signCertificateRequest(std::vector<unsigned char>& certificate_request)
{
    // You'll need an open session and be logged in

    CK_OBJECT_CLASS private_key_class = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY;
    CK_KEY_TYPE private_key_type = CKK_RSA;
    std::array<unsigned char, 4> id = "myid";
    std::vector<CK_ATTRIBUTE> private_key_template = {
        { CKA_CLASS, &private_key_class, sizeof(private_key_class) },
        { CKA_KEY_TYPE, &private_key_type, sizeof(private_key_type) },
        { CKA_ID, id.data(), static_cast<long>(id.size()) },
    };

    auto result = s_pkcs11->fn->C_FindObjectsInit(m_session_handle,
                                                  private_key_template.data(),
                                                  static_cast<unsigned long>(private_key_template.size()));

    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE private_key_handle { 0 };
    unsigned long object_count { 0 };
    result = s_pkcs11->fn->C_FindObjects(m_session_handle, &private_key_handle, 1, &object_count);
    result = s_pkcs11->fn->C_FindObjectsFinal(m_session_handle);

    CK_MECHANISM mechanism = { CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS, nullptr, 0 };
    auto result = s_pkcs11->fn->C_SignInit(m_session_handle, &mechanism, private_key_handle);

    unsigned long signature_length { 0 };
    result = s_pkcs11->fn->C_Sign(m_session_handle,
                                  certificate_request.data(),
                                  static_cast<unsigned long>(certificate_request.size()),
                                  nullptr,
                                  &signature_length);

    std::vector<unsigned char> signature(signature_length);
    result = s_pkcs11->fn->C_Sign(m_session_handle,
                                  certificate_request.data(),
                                  static_cast<unsigned long>(certificate_request.size()),
                                  signature.data(),
                                  &signature_length);
    return signature;
}
```